# In google maps javascript api - how to move map not marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

currently i have a little project that needs to make marker static and move map to the marker display on the map - i hope it makes any sense -

how to move map not marker - like i said the marker cannot move but the map needs to move to the marker when location changed - also marker is displayed at the bottom the map to make room for other events above the marker such as a path display and etc -

whats done already is when car moves it watches gps - then tells marker to move to that gps as a current location and then panby to the bottom of the map - this makes marker jerk at the bottom of the map when its location changed - so i figured if i keep marker static by placing it into a div above map and fixate it via css style - so it stays in the same place all the time - but this is wrong as it cannot be moved with map then when someone drags map with a finger - so this cannot be  right solution - what is your solution to this dilema unless i am missing something -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to **rotate** the map on the correct axis, **find the position** of the center of the map, and finally **center the map** at the right place.

## 1 - Rotate the map

In your case (I presume you want the car always face of the road in front of the user position) you need to rotate the map before centering, otherwise the map is always oriented to the north and it can be anoying when the car move in other orientation (south for exemple). In this case the point of view is oriented in the wrong direction and the user don't see the upcoming road.

You can find an exemple [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/webgl/tilt-rotation) in the documentation. Basicaly you need to use `setHeading()` method. The rotation on gmap is not easy than it can be (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666999/11630806)).

## 2 - Find the center of the map

To find the updated position of the center of your map, you need to retrieve the latLng location of a point always at the same distance (in pixel of the map container) above your marker fixed location. Use the methods `fromLatLngToPoint()` and `fromPointToLatLng()` to retrieve the position from the map to the real world or vice versa (see [`getProjection()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#Projection) for more details).

**Exemple :**

Your map is displayed in 1000*1000 px  and the bottom position of the marker you choose is at 500px of the left side and 950px of the top side. If you want to move the center of the map without changing the position of the marker, you need to find the latLng position of the point at 450px above your marker.

```
function findMapCenter(map, markerLatLng) {
    // need this to adjust from the actual zoom on the map
    let scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    // position in pixel x.y from the container
    let markerWorldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(markerLatLng);
    // calcul of the position of the center
    let centerWorldCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
        markerWorldCoordinate.x,
        markerWorldCoordinate.y + (450/scale) // 450 because in my exemple is from 450px at the top of the marker
    );
    // return latLng of the center point of the map
    return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(centerWorldCoordinate);
}
```

## 3 - Set the map at the right place

Use [`setCenter()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setCenter) method to center the map on a choosen latLng location.

```
let marker; // = config of your marker
let gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
update({lat:MARKER_LATITUDE, lng:MARKER_LONGITUDE});

// call this every time you want to update
function update(markerNewLatLng){
    // ... first step : rotate the map if you need to
    // then update marker position
    marker.setPosition(markerNewLatLng);
    // center the map
    gMap.setCenter(findMapCenter(gmap, markerNewLatLng));
}
```

Comment: so you are saying is that if i have a dynamic LatLng that changes depending on car motion (imaging a car marker) and it is positioned at the bottom of the map - then the marker will stay in place without jerking up and down and the map seemlessly pan to that center where the car marker is - and i repeat the car marker needs to be at the bottom of the map - thus the center of the map where the car marker is - i have a feeling that it maybe not enough for that to happen after setting the map center in a dynamic manner - just brainstorming on your reply - thanks by the way!

Comment: I modified my post a little bit to be more specific. I hope i understand your question and it can help you.

Comment: in order to stick the marker at the bottom, had to change from 450 to -450 - other than that works like a charm - i even went ahead and test it with the map-listerner-onclick so when you click map anywhere - the marker (no jerk!) staying in place and map moves to that marker at the bottom - thank you!!